# Sinatra Server not serving Files with a '+' in Name

Tags: sinatra

Some of my files in my Sinatra server's public folder have a '+' in their names. 
When I try to access these files via browser, I get a 404 error. There is no additional log output.

I triple-checked that the files do exist and the URL is correct. I can access other files in the public folder. If I rename these files, so they don't contain a '+' in their name, I can access them as well.

Unfortunately, I can not avoid having '+' characters in my filenames.

Has this been experienced before?

Comment: You could list some of the files here.  It may be helpful.

Comment: one of the filenames is

5.5.0-0icu-linux-g++-Rhel6.6-x86.7z.sha1, but I can reproduce the error with every filename that contains a '+'.

Comment: "and the URL is correct" If possible, I'd like to see what you consider to be a correct URL using the example of `5.5.0-0icu-linux-g++-Rhel6.6-x86.7z.sha1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit in the Sinatra source appears to be this line:

```
  path = File.expand_path("#{public_dir}#{unescape(request.path_info)}"
```

whose behaviour boils down to

```
URI.decode_www_form_component('a+b', 'utf-8')  # returns "a b"
```

Before this line any `+` characters in request.path_info are replaced with a space.

It sounds like you intend to use this webserver for more than a simple project. In that case, I would highly recommend you do not use Sinatra as a file server but instead hide it behind a reverse-proxy such as nginx which is highly optimized for sending files. If nginx cannot find the file it will forward the request to the sinatra webserver to handle.

Comment: I think you are on the right track here. i also posted this issue in the sinatra issue board: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1031#issuecomment-138603036